# Javascript OOP query re DOM

Tags: javascript, oop, dom

can you use parameters some how to alter 'book' and 'person' in this statement :
   **book.borrower= person**;  eg  JSObj.borrower = "SteveJobs";
I cannot seem to find a way,
Is there one?

Comment: There is no DOM involved in any of the code you have there, and nothing that takes parameters. You should probably rephrase your question, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you meant to have something like this:

```
function changeBorrower(book, person)
{
    book.borrower = person;
}

// USAGE
changeBorrower(JSObj, "SteveJobs");
```

Comment: Makram, thanks for your response
In fact I have similar code ie

function loanbook (book, lender) {
book.borrower = lender;
alert(book.borrower);
}
loanbook("JSObj", "Frank");
but its not working??

Comment: Further to your response, I noticed you had no "" around JSObj
I have removed mine and it works fine, why is that?
Thank you so much
Alan

Comment: Because a string literal and a variable are completely different things.

Comment: David,thanks...what a bunny...i've just started playing with OOP. 
I understand now, thank you for your response